# Typescript Error, thrown even after && short-circuit evaluation

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors

Please read the code below

```
type type1 = string[] | undefined;

let variable1 : type1 = undefined;

console.log(variable1 && variable1.length);
```

Attempting to execute the aforementioned code in Typescript Playground, results in the following code
**Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'.**

Why does typescript throw error the possibility of variable1 being a falsy value has been handled by **&&** short-circuit evaluation.

I have also tried using ?. option chaining, but it is logically the same thing as above code.

I am expecting typescript to not show any error.
It is a necessity to have undefined as a posible value of variable1, there are typeOf checks for conditions in my code.

Answer (score 2):

This is because TypeScript already knows that you will be assigning `undefined` to the variable `variable1`.

Instead, you can do this so TypeScript will not be smart enough to auto detect the type that you are assigning to `variable1`:

```
type type1 = string[] | undefined;

let variable1 = undefined as type1;

console.log(variable1 && variable1.length);
```

Alternatively, try to indirectly refers to the `type1` type like so, which TypeScript will not be able to find it immediately:

```
type type1 = string[] | undefined;

function getSomeType(): type1 {
    return undefined;
}

let variable1 = getSomeType();

console.log(variable1 && variable1.length);
```