# Typescript cannot determine the type of a variable, only in one part of the condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to write a type that, depending on the passed value of multiple, the active and onChange types changed

Here it is

```
export type IconSelectorProps = {
    className?: string;
    name: string;
    items: SelectorItem[];
} & (MultipleSelector | SingleSelector);

type SingleSelector = { multiple: false } & Selector<SelectorItem>;
type MultipleSelector = { multiple: true } & Selector<SelectorItem[]>;

interface Selector<T> {
    active: T;
    onChange: (item: T) => void;
}

export interface SelectorItem {
    icon: string;
    value: string;
    title?: string;
}
```

However, if you use a function that, depending on multiple, should transmit a different data type to onChange, it flashes an error to me

Code

```
const setActiveItem = (item: SelectorItem) => {
    if (multiple && active.some((e) => e.value == item.value)) {
        onChange([...active, item]);
    } else if (active.value !== item.value) {
        onChange(item);
    }
};
```

Error's

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'SelectorItem | SelectorItem[]'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'SelectorItem[]'.
```

```
Argument of type 'SelectorItem' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectorItem[] & SelectorItem'.
  Type 'SelectorItem' is missing the following properties from type 'SelectorItem[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

The most interesting moment. that in `if` ts understands everything, and in `else if` ts immediately breaks down

[Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgEk0IA7AZSQBskNoAFHGADOcALxwA3uThw0nFEKEA5FCCQB+AFxwhMKMBYBzCjJaqk23fqMm4wGEhBDtHbrygMHIANoBdCgC+cABkcAAUALIArpwwwGDcrjww0HAAPnBsBoaJXMnQAJQUVLT0WUa5bilQYpJwIDFxCRZwmCicQvRBoUnuADy91Z6OAHwUNHRw0bHxlfk14hL1jbMtelFdIZl5-YPQwz6+Y5QGDlBtaGU71X0AKiOS0nDocQBuLbe2rADCABYoRhaYXsjm0twKYgerwgwAAJoFKEgAB6QWB2FhnC5XKr7LyPGTAZgsSx6bK2V7tDYk6zGJ5xGDcLQ6Uk2cgBShE3RwBy6bRMVh7KACCDCWpSUzmbT4HkwfAAGieL2A7203ieMnFMi1hNYUpl8vVWopnCpBH1Cq1Wvp3D1SF0BstAQtcF8zoaM2a2nWSGdIKcqsNmstOuJZrtsudluNpul4Ydlu59htYftkbgTqerqeP3+gO0wK8ENEDyDslYQgg3AAdJwIIYC44ik8M+zyJz4JqzGpnUr3m6Vs1fV4hM6cwDDJtxDLiu2dEgYABBDDKpAHWoNkAua64xuQ-F2TDhd1NbghUK9pBVitqMJhJBFh6X6P0UTiP1V58FCGlseAsLeKtAIvOU7C8XwmxkIIuE6A9wgvD9KXoABCV9QMcBCTXvfcZF-CcNwg9M2Rnct4E6Rdl3eA4AEZ1z9LccQ8Qs901YBDzCY9Vm-Q1WLgijL2vJBbyw4s4CfRCxDfLwMI2L9sK1XDBIAoC+JAv1wNsSDm1Ejp6B4sJ4OfOAUMk9DPzqAB6cy4AAcSiFAoABBw7W5CA4AAI2QjjmkNBT8NsdkAmIlguTIpc3lXLwACZaK8ej5gOB99z0rzT2Cc8+KvXBBLvRKxMwiS0JAaT7y4y1fKUqtgMK9TmyeaDdLYpCUvoNLngywzjMK4rvzgSybLshyMSQZyUnczyB24HyWD+cdBL9AiAqCrkiBYWEkEYxx10SzVZyEVRmgAERQGAUFqNVLVLGQJhaAAiBcbrTGRmCiDFtCoyK0wzGR-CeIgYCiKAWDgPpYWVEY+nM0HXmOQLyCAA)

Answer (score 0):

(There are multiple reasons to why the original code fails, TLDR is the condition in `if` statement is not right, and using constant value caused TypeScript to short-circuit and inferred the type to a stricter format)

This is because there can be scenario where `multiple` is true but it doesn't fulfil your condition of `active.some((e) => e.value == item.value)`.

If you make it into 2 `if` statements, it should detect fine that `else if` is `!multiple`:

```
const setActiveItem = (item: SelectorItem) => {
  if (multiple) {
    if (active.some((e) => e.value == item.value)) {
      onChange([...active, item]);
    }
  } else if (active.value !== item.value) { // Guarantees to be !multiple
    onChange(item);
  }
};
```

---

Imagine this scenario in your original code:

```
const setActiveItem = (item: SelectorItem) => {
  if (multiple && active.some((e) => e.value == item.value)) {
    onChange([...active, item]);
  } else if (active.value !== item.value) { // Only guarantees to be !(multiple && active.some((e) => e.value == item.value))
    onChange(item);
  }
};
```

| `multiple` | `active.some((e) => e.value == item.value)` | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `true` | `true` | Working fine, `onChange([...active, item]);` is triggered |
| `false` | N/A | Working fine, since `multiple` is false, `active` is an object |
| `true` | `false` | This is the case where TypeScript is complaining about, you can't be sure `active` is an array in the `else if` statement because `multiple` is still true |

---

In addition, as `test` is a hard-coded constant, TypeScript is smart enough to know that `multiple` is always `true` and `active` is always an array (Refers to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76120226/8888888) I gave to another question)

A fix would be to indirectly reference to your `test` object like so:

```
const test: IconSelectorProps = {
  name: 'test',
  active: [
    {
      icon: 'test',
      value: 'test',
      title: 'test',
    },
  ],
  multiple: true,
  items: [
    {
      icon: 'test',
      value: 'test',
      title: 'test',
    },
  ],
  onChange: (item) => {
    console.log(item);
  },
};

function getTest(): IconSelectorProps {
  return test;
}

const {
  name,
  active,
  multiple,
  items,
  onChange } = getTest();
```

---

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgEk0IA7AZSQBskNoAFHGADOcALxwA3uThw0nFEKEA5FCCQB+AFxwhMKMBYBzCjJaqk23fqMm4wGEhBDtHbrygMHIANoBdCgC+cABkcAAUALIArpwwwGDcrjww0HAAPnBsBoaJXMnQAJQUVLT0WUa5bilQYpJwIDFxCRZwmCicQvRBoUnuADy91Z6OAHwUNHRw0bHxlfk14hL1jbMtelFdIZl5-YPQwz6+Y5QGDlBtaGU71X0AKiOS0nDocQBuLbe2rADCABYoRhaYXsjm0twKYgerwgwAAJoFKEgAB6QWB2FhnC5XKr7LyPGTAZgsSx6bK2V7tDYk6zGJ5xGDcLQ6Uk2cgBShE3SMIl7BbhMCCZzc1i8gQQYQQ0QPKQyTnwJZmNQAGmeGGA7xVDRmzRVIKcKp+-0BcCC4gF4qExVlrC5nRgAEE1e8DrVgV4XNdcY5JdKngTMOEtU1uCFQi91UgAHRCXBIMJhJA+uBRimcDZicR6yOpjYFCEymSFw0Awxx7yRivhjV2Ly+Ip+k3Jjr0YABsJVlOU+gAQlEma82a7+YbMmLgLd3tsMnZ06tsht8DtjreSAOAHVoABrbKuvUenEeLxJgv+wMrZrDwuF1vhDvR2PxxOQ5ODtP0Ps1xyv3OXq9Flh-CWZYVpGHa6rW9Z-iaDZBFwnR2G2d45j2H5Zshv5XmOpYTiAkGFjOJpzkQMBRFALBwCwMScIExR9EwIqelATyKkgogAEQOLobFPEGqxPB2ogSN4SyEqw2j4JxMD4CqyHiZJ0lwPS3ByUguj4CavgEXqQiCcJdhEipakyV2hlSSqSktBJqlSRpBFYaxEg4ce84sDG3CRpwECGE5pAmuyAD0xxAA)

Comment: If you refer to the live example, you will see that just such in the case of `if` everything works, and it makes no sense to allocate it to a separate `if`. and the block with `else if` just doesn't work

Comment: Hi @dzhd, yes I understand, the problem is because the second condition `active.some((e) => e.value == item.value)` can return `false`. If it returns `false`, there's no way to guarantee that the `active` in your `else if` is not an array.

Comment: I have updated the Live Example, including with your solution option, as you can see - the error has not gone away

Comment: Hi @dzhd, interestingly I believe I know why. This is the same issue as this one that I just answered yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76120226/8888888 - I have also modified the answer again to show the reason.

Comment: Test is a written constant for example, in the original code it is react props. + Based on your statement that TS, seeing a constant, always understands that it is true, then in the opposite case (if multiple = false) it would have to show a different error in another place, but it does not. Also, using the form of getting data from a function (not a static object) does not solve this problem, and the vehicle also shows the same error - https://i.stack.imgur.com/p83p5.png

Comment: Hi @dzhd, I have added a TypeScript Playground link in the answer above, hope it explains why it works (or doesn't), please take a look yourself, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but yes, I still see the same problem, but now in the react example, and unfortunately I still don't understand why it doesn't work, because the interfaces and types are written correctly, and your variations give the same result (which doesn't work)